# Encrypt A String With JavaScript And Decrypt It From Server Side (Java)

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, encryption

I need to encrypt a string at client side and send it to the server.
Once there I need to decrypt it.

Is the **[Using Password-Based Encryption](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#PBEEx)** the best solution?

I need it because I have a voting mechanism, where I send ajax posts to vote an entry.
This mechanism use the Facebook id from the current user. My goal is to encrypt the FB id from client side to avoid that they hack it by sending requests with differents ids.
If a second post with the same id is sent I will block the vote.

Once the id is decrypted I will check if it is a real FB user using the graph.

Comment: Note that the encryption wont help you in this case, they will be able replicate your encryption and send it to the server with whatever id they want.

Comment: Sessions that are connected to a user might be an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that there is no authentication an HTTP fingerprint can be used to check if requests with different userId come from the same user.

Fingerprint will be create from HTTP request data like:

-user agent
   -language
   -IP
   -charset

and other data present in the http request.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript encryption won't help here.  Any good detective/hacker can see how it's all done on the client and see what the data was before it was encrypted and see how it's encrypted.

The only way to prevent a user from voting multiple times is to have the vote tied to an account or token that you can both verify on your server and tie to a particular user that isn't easy for the user to make lots of different accounts.  In general, you probably can't stop this entirely, but you can make it enough trouble that most won't do it by making it require enough steps (including some sort of captcha so it can't be automated).

SSL will protect client/server communications, but won't do anything to stop the client from doing things you don't want them to do.

Comment: All my comments combined together and formulated better in an answer, very nice! :)

Answer (score 0):

“Encryption” does not make any sense here as you have already been told (because the value that would be encrypted client-side could be manipulated *before* you encrypt it), and SSL does of course not solve this problem either.

Send the **access token** of the user to the server instead. And then either make a request for user data with it (`/me`), or [debug it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#debug) – then you will know that the request is genuine, because a user can not “fake” an access token for another user.